# Export plot to editable excel

Tags: ggplot2, export-to-excel

Yesterday I asked for exporting plot from R to editable powerpoint. Today I'd like to use the same data set to export plot from R to editable Excel. I followed this article https://blog.enterprisedna.co/ggplot2-plots-in-excel-for-advanced-data-visualizations/, and the plot in Excel was an image. But what I need is an editable plot in Excel. I tryd the code `dml_xlsx`, but it produces this error 'Error: Expecting a single string value: [type=list; extent=9]'. Could you please help me to figure out how to fix this error, and probably some following errors that my codes might produce?

```
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(knitr)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(mschart)
library(here)
library(purrr)

Project_stages<-read_excel("/Users/giang/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-GCF/Documents/R/Test w R/Project stages 131122.xlsx")

head(Project_stages)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, 'analysis')
addWorksheet(wb, "analysis2")

Project_stages_1 <- Project_stages%>%
  filter(Stage %in% c("00. PI received",
       "01. Stage 3: CN received",
       "04. Stage 4: FP received",
       "14. Stage 6: Approved")) %>%
  spread(key = Stage, value = 'Day of Stage Date') %>% 
    select(`Approved Ref`,Index,PI =`00. PI received`,
             CN=`01. Stage 3: CN received`,
              FP=`04. Stage 4: FP received`,
                Approved='14. Stage 6: Approved') %>% 
     mutate(Project_received= as.Date((ifelse(!is.na(PI), as.character(PI), 
                                                ifelse(!is.na(CN), as.character(CN), 
                                                       ifelse(!is.na(FP), as.character(FP), "")))),
                                      format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
    filter(Index==1) %>% 
    mutate(duration= as.numeric(difftime(Approved,Project_received, units = "days")), Sub_Year= as.numeric(format(Project_received, format= "%Y")))


xcel_stages <-Project_stages_1 %>% 
  select(duration, Sub_Year) %>% 
  group_by(Sub_Year) %>% 
  summarise(Avrg= round(mean(duration)),
            Mdn= round(median(duration)))

writeDataTable(wb, 'analysis2', x=xcel_stages)

xplot <- ggplot(xcel_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill= "#2f8c80")+
  theme_minimal()+
  ggtitle("Duration of project submission to GCF")

xplot

xplot_dml <-dml_xlsx(file = xplot, width = 6, height = 4, offx = 1, offy = 1, bg = "white", pointsize = 12, editable = TRUE, id = 1L, raster_prefix = "raster_", standalone = TRUE)

read_xlsx() %>%
  xl_add_vg(xplot_dml, sheet = "analysis2", code = print(gg), width = 6, height = 4, left = 1, top = 2) %>%
  print(target = here("results.xlsx"))
```

FYI, I'm using Markdown in MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to handle it, but data and graph are in different sheets,"analysis2" and "analysis3". Really appreciated if someone can help to put them into one sheet only.

```
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(officer)
library(rvg)
library(here)

Project_stages<-read_excel("/Users/giang/Library/CloudStorage/OneDrive-GCF/Documents/R/Test w R/Project stages 131122.xlsx")

head(Project_stages)

Project_stages_1 <- Project_stages%>%
  filter(Stage %in% c("00. PI received",
       "01. Stage 3: CN received",
       "04. Stage 4: FP received",
       "14. Stage 6: Approved")) %>%
  spread(key = Stage, value = 'Day of Stage Date') %>% 
    select(`Approved Ref`,Index,PI =`00. PI received`,
             CN=`01. Stage 3: CN received`,
              FP=`04. Stage 4: FP received`,
                Approved='14. Stage 6: Approved') %>% 
     mutate(Project_received= as.Date((ifelse(!is.na(PI), as.character(PI), 
                                                ifelse(!is.na(CN), as.character(CN), 
                                                       ifelse(!is.na(FP), as.character(FP), "")))),
                                      format="%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
    filter(Index==1) %>% 
    mutate(duration= as.numeric(difftime(Approved,Project_received, units = "days")), Sub_Year= as.numeric(format(Project_received, format= "%Y")))

xcel_stages <-Project_stages_1 %>% 
  select(duration, Sub_Year) %>% 
  group_by(Sub_Year) %>% 
  summarise(Avrg= round(mean(duration)),
            Mdn= round(median(duration)))


wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "analysis2")

writeDataTable(wb, 'analysis2', x=xcel_stages)

xcelplot <- ggplot(xcel_stages, aes(x= Sub_Year, y= Avrg))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill= "#2f8c80")+
  theme_minimal()+
  ggtitle("Duration of project submission to GCF")
print(xcelplot)
dev.off()

tmp <-tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")
saveWorkbook(wb, tmp, overwrite = TRUE)

officerwb <- read_xlsx(tmp)
file.remove(tmp)
officerwb <- add_sheet(officerwb, label = "analysis3")
officerwb <- xl_add_vg(officerwb, sheet = "analysis3", code = print(xcelplot), width = 6, height = 4, left = 1, top = 2)
print(officerwb, target = here("results.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Please try to remove all unnecessary parts of your code to produce a *minimal* working example. This will help find an answer to your problem and make the question more helpful to others once it's answered.